# Getting error "xargs unterminated quote" when tried to print the number of lines in terminal

Tags: macos, xargs

I want to get the number of lines in my application. I am using this code:

```
find . "(" -name "*.m" -or -name "*.h" ")" -print | xargs wc -l
```

It is working fine in other applications but for one of my applications it is giving the error "xargs unterminated quote".

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Does one of your filenames have a quote in it?  Try something like this:

```
find . "(" -name "*.m" -or -name "*.h" ")" -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
```

The `-print0` argument tells `find` to use the NULL character to terminate each name that it prints out.  The `-0` argument tells `xargs` that its input tokens are NULL-terminated.  This avoids issues with characters that otherwise would be treated as special, like quotes.

Comment: I tried to remove all .svn folder and below is worked for me:  
find ./ -name ".svn" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -Rf

Comment: The `find . -print0 | xargs -0` is the important bit, took me a few seconds because I didn't read the text underneath ‍♂️

Answer (score 19):

This can happen because you have a single quote in a filename somewhere...

i.e., -> `'`

To find the problem file, run the following in the terminal:

```
\find . | grep \'
```

you can also run xargs like so to effectively address this issue:

```
xargs -I
```

and it can also happen if you have an alias for xargs setup that's causing an issue. To test if this is the case, just run xargs with a `\` in front of it, e.g.

```
\find . | \xargs ....
```

The \ simply means "run the command without any aliases"

Answer (score 5):

The canonical way to solve quotes, spaces and special characters problems when using `find` is to use the `-exec` option instead of `xargs`.

For your case you can use:

```
find . "(" -name "*.m" -or -name "*.h" ")" -exec wc -l "{}" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering, I found that this command worked for me (because I had spaces and unmatched quotations in my filenames):

`find . -iname "*USA*" -exec cp "{}" /Directory/to/put/file/ \;`

`.` refers to the location the search is being run

`-iname` followed by the expression refers to the match criteria

`-exec cp "{}" /Directory/to/put/file/ \;` tells the command to execute the copy command where each file found via `-iname` replaces `"{}"`

You need the `\;` to denote to the exec command that the `cp` statement is ending.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by replacing from source `"` with `\"`